# How to remove excerpt, comments and date from WordPress archive pages?

Tags: wordpress

How can I remove the excerpt, number of comments and the date from all archive pages on WordPress? I dont want to use CSS for this because SEO problemlatics. I only would like to keep the featured image and the title.

Is there a opportunity with the function.php or so?

Comment: Can nobody help? :/

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I use Enfold theme